# Javascript scrolling and moving positions

Tags: javascript, scroll

The window object in js has a scrollBy() method, which takes two arguments, what do those arguments represent? The book where im learning this from says "the number of pixels to scoll by, but what does it mean. does it mean when i drag the scroll bar on the right side it will move the content by 10 pixels or if I click the down or up scroll button it will move the content by 10 pixels that I specified or what?

Also, I can't seem to understand the difference between the moveTo() method and the moveBy() method they seem like they do the exact same thing, but if that the case then whats the point in having two functions that do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

the parameters are top and left coordinates in pixel.

scrollTo and scrollBy methods are same with one exception. scrollTo works as absolute coordinates, scrollBy works as relative to current scroll position.

same rule applies to moveTo and moveBy methods.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for a lot of duplicate properties in javascript is that all browsers have their own implementation of it. MoveTo moves to the specified amount of pixels **from the top** while moveBy moves the view by a specified amount of pixels **from the current position**

A good tool to inspect the usage of javascript properties is the firebug browser plugin. Highly recommended. http://getfirebug.com/